# Reading a Text File w/ WIN32

Tags: c++, winapi, file-io

I'm trying to parse a text file with a win32 program in c++. Is there a simple method of reading a text file line by line? My text file consists of strings that I would like to store in a char array(const char* cArray[67]). Here is what I have so far. I am using CreateFile and ReadFile. I get an access violation error(0x000003e6) from readfile:

```
CDECK::CDECK():filename(".\\Deck/list.txt")
{
    LPVOID data = NULL;
    hFile = CreateFileA(filename, GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to CreateFile - 'hFile'", L"CDECK::CDECK()", MB_OK);

    DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, &fileSize);
    DWORD read = -1;
    if(!ReadFile(hFile, data, fileSize, &read, NULL))
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to ReadFile - 'hFile'", L"CDECK::CDECK()", MB_OK);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Too bad you can't use something like Python for this.....

Comment: Do you *have* to use winapi calls directly? Can you use `std::ifstream` to read the data, and store the results in a `std::vector<std::string>` ?

Comment: It's unbelievable the contortions that the Win32 API goes to in making simple tasks as hard as possible.  Try that in plain old C++; easy.  Python, Ruby, Perl... easy, easy, easy.  Even good old C isn't too bad if you know what you're doing.  But layer in the Windows API, and you're suddenly shot through a wormhole to the Borg's belly.

Comment: @DavidO win32 interface is pretty much identical to C's open/read

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a simple method of reading a text file line by line?

Yes:

```
{
  std::ifstream hFile(filename);

  std::vector<std::string> lines;
  std::string line;
  while(std::getline(hFile, line))
    lines.push_back(line);

  return lines;
}
```

Comment: Won't that get the text word by word rather than line by line?

Comment: d'uh. Of course. Fixed. Amazing that three people upvoted my patently incorrect answer, though.

Answer (score 6):

Consider this code:

```
LPVOID data = NULL;
if(!ReadFile(hFile, data, fileSize, &read, NULL))
```

Here `data` is null, and the following argument is the size of the entire file. You are supposed to allocate a buffer, and then pass a pointer to such buffer and its size to it. There is where the `ReadFile` function will write the readed bytes.

Here is a simple way of getting it to work with a statically sized buffer:

```
char data[4096] = {};
if(!ReadFile(hFile, static_cast< LPVOID >( &data ), 4096, &read, NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are reading the bytes of the file, to read the string you need to alloc a string location using **SysAllocStringByteLen** and then use the ReadFile

Comment: where on Earth did you get the requirement of using `SysAllocStringByteLen` from?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms221637(v=vs.85).aspx
or you can just use VirtualAlloc aswell, the idea is to alloc a virtual space before reading it.

Comment: Windows BSTRings (as produced by `SysAllocstringByteLen`) are used exclusively for COM/OLE code, there is no advantage to them otherwise. ReadFile is happy with any buffer. The simplest is `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to allocate a buffer space before reading your data :
LPVOID data = NULL;

Before reading you must allocate a fileSize buffer space :
data = malloc(fileSize);

And probably must also declare your data variable as char* instead of void*